# React Reduxjs toolkit is not reading state in useSelector, using Typescript. Is shows me an error that loggedIn is not a boolean

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm passing to the component  a state from store.tsx file and it shows me an error.
Error is in const loggedIn that state.loggedIn.loggedIn is not a boolean.
Below is the code for component

```
  import React from "react";
import { StyledNavBar, StyledNavButton } from "./styles";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const NavBar = () => {
  interface IisLoggedInProp {
    loggedIn: boolean;
  }

  **const loggedIn = useSelector(
    (state: IisLoggedInProp) => state.loggedIn.loggedIn
  );**

  return (
    <StyledNavBar>
      <StyledNavButton>Dodaj Post</StyledNavButton>
      {loggedIn && <StyledNavButton>Dodaj Komentarz</StyledNavButton>}
      <StyledNavButton>Toggluj kolory</StyledNavButton>
      <StyledNavButton>Wyślij wiadomość</StyledNavButton>
    </StyledNavBar>
  );
};
```

And this is how store.js looks like
I have cancelled logOutSlice from provided code to don't make confusion.

```
 import { createSlice, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialLoggedInState = {
  loggedIn: false,
};

const loggedInSlice = createSlice({
  name: "loggedIn",
  initialState: initialLoggedInState,
  reducers: {
    withLogIn(state) {
      state.loggedIn = true;
    },
    withoutLogIn(state) {
      state.loggedIn = false;
    },
  },
});

export const loggedInActions = loggedInSlice.actions;   

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { loggedIn: loggedInSlice.reducer, logOut: logOutSlice.reducer },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSelector` always reads from your root state, so instead of `IisLoggedInProp` you have to use your `RootState` type there.

Answer (score 1):

the state type is `RootState`

Do it this way

```
const loggedIn = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.loggedIn.loggedIn
  );
```